# Перенос JavaScript в конец страницы в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Ситуация в следующем, есть проект на bitrix 15.0.6 версии, где имеется ряд модификаций ядра битрикса, что соответственно не позволят "по простому" обновиться. Появилась задача реализовать перенос всего js-кода/скриптов в конец страницы, для этого решили задействовать стандартный функционал bitrix версии 15.5.1, в которой эта возможность появилась. Собственно перенесли ядро (модификации пока еще не применяли), функционал появился и заработал, но по какой-то причине начал вырезать скрипты на половину, обрывая часть контента, тем самым руша верстку и подключая скрипты в закомментированный участок кода. 
Может кто подскажет, где находиться модуль или регулярка ответственная за парсинг скриптов?

Оригинал блока кода выглядит так:

```
<!-- num 6 code -->
        (labla<script type="text/javascript">
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        </script>labla)
```

Сноска: "labla" - это чисто флаг, чтобы проще было в верстке найти.

После переноса Js получается, на том месте остается:

```
<!-- num 6 | [];
    </script>labla)
```

В конце же страницы, идет начало этого блока:

```
code -->
        (labla<script type="text/javascript">
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer |
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще использование этой галочки может повлиять на производительность сайта из-за собственно парсинга страницы. Регистрацию большинства служебных скриптов у Битрикса все равно нужно делать в шапке. Поэтому я предлагаю использовать следующее решение.

За регистрацию скриптов отвечают методы `SetAdditionalCSS()` и `AddHeadScript()`. Их можно оставить в шапке.

Затем в `header.php` и `footer.php` определите переменную

```
$bScriptInFooter = !$USER->isAdmin();
```

Как можно догадаться это будет условие для перемещения скриптов в подвал страницы. Почему не нужно переносить для всех? Потому что тяжело и практически невозможно до сих пор добиться работоспособности панели администратора при переносе ее подключения в футер.

Теперь в `header.php` пишем:

```
<?php 
   $APPLICATION->ShowCSS();
   if (!$bScriptInFooter) {
      $APPLICATION->ShowHeadStrings();
      $APPLICATION->ShowHeadScripts();
   }  
   ?>
```

А в `footer.php`

```
<?php
if ($bScriptInFooter) {
   $APPLICATION->ShowHeadStrings();
   $APPLICATION->ShowHeadScripts();
}
?>
```

Для работы этого способа все скрипты и стили которые дополнительно подключаются в шаблонах компонентов должны регистрироваться через `SetAdditionalCSS()` и `AddHeadScript()`